# Accessing Wrapping Wordpress Shortcode Content From Another Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two plugins. A core plugin used provide store information and an inventory plugin that retrieve inventory from any given store within a database.

The core plugin has a shortcode called store, it can be passed in a specific store's id or if not passed in within the shortcode it uses a default store id.

What I'd like to do is use the store shortcode as a wrapping shortcode that passes its content into another shortcode.

Kind of like this

```
[store store_id = "some store id"]
    [inventory]
[/store]
```

Is it possible for the function used in the inventory shortcode to have access to the data returned from the wrapping store shortcode?

Comment: If inventory plugin needs to be related to store and these plugins are not developed by you and are perhaps by different authors then you are probably in a "pickle".

As much as I know about Wordpress you need to develop another custom tag for this functionality.

Comment: Both plugins are plugins I am developing

Comment: Ok. Do the shortcodes evaluate in this combination? In this case you could throw some flag into some global state and poll it in the inventory plugin. Fragile, but keeps one going. I have not worked with WP for a long time but there's probably some global cache or container which could be used for this.

Comment: Ok. I found this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/
In this case you could either programtically replace some shortcode parameters or use some global state or just plainly call your shortcode do_shortcode('[inventory store=x]');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest option would be to pass the parent tag's store ID to the nested tag and do in the inventory what you need, what is dependent on the store.

So based on the good reading on this article(https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/) I would suggest such a solution:

**Example with ID**
You add a optional parameter for the inventory tag - store_id, and set it in the content to be for example {store_id}.

In the store short code/plugin you are gonna replace the {store_id} with the current store ID and evaluate the short code content with do_shortcode(). 
*(So in a way you implement your own short codes :) )*

In the post content

```
[store store_id = "some store id"]
    [inventory store_id={store_id}]
[/store]
```

In the store plugin/shortcode:

```
$content = str_replace($content, '{store_id}', $myCurrentStoreId);
return do_shortcode($content);
```

**Answer to your question**
Yes, as far as the short code syntax supports data passed as parameters you could send whatever from the wrapping short codes using the solution provided in the article. I suspect that the parameters for short codes are really meant for short strings and id's (in case you meant to send a long html page in it).

*WP docs - do_shortcode:* https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Sorry I'm either drunk, sleepy or lacking english abilities. My wording is messed up.